# Unable to create project in GCP CLI with user (name@gmail.com) having Owner, Project Billing Manager role

Tags: gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-resource-manager

User **name@gmail.com** is able to create new project from GCP console. User has OWNER/Project Billing Manager role but when trying to create new project from CLI, it shows:

```
gcloud auth login -> Successful login with user@gmail.com

user@cloudshell:~ (gcp-ace-292306)$ gcloud auth list
   Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       user@gmail.com

user@cloudshell:~ (gcp-ace-292306)$ gcloud projects list
PROJECT_ID      NAME     PROJECT_NUMBER
gcp-ace-292306  GCP ACE  350766525882  -> This project is created in console by same user.

user@cloudshell:~ (gcp-ace-292306)$ gcloud projects create proj-100 --name=demo-project1 --enable-cloud-apis --labels=dept=it,env=prod --folder=12345
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.create) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

Am I missing some other role here? Can anyone suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem although from a cloud instance.

Select IAM & Admin in the google cloud console.
Select the folder you want to create the project in.
[image: Select the folder]
Then give Project Creator role to the member which is trying to create the project.

For me the member was -compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

If the member is not listed then you can add the member and assign roles.